# When to use mark edges as sharp and when to use bevel

Tags: modeling, edges

I am a novice blender user and I am just trying to get my head around when to mark edges as sharp, when use bevel, and when to just shade flat. I'm working on a victorian street lamp, very early stages as you can see. I am just wondering in this case which approach I should use if I want to keep the edges sharp? I am ultimately hoping to texture and render out the object in a scene.

[image]

Comment: I would say there is no general rule, especially if you take into account game engines.
I think its about being able to choose suitable scenario once aware of differences in different approaches . For me in most cases setting all faces to shade smooth, in geometry properties-"Normals" group ticking Auto Smooth works. Then only if I want to force some edge to be "creased" I will mark it as sharp. beveling an edge will create actual geometry between the surfaces, making smooth transition as the result. Shading is just a visual effect, like good old https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading

Comment: Thank you so much Rafal, this is very helpful! So is there any practical difference between 1. leaving the object shaded flat if corners and flat faces are desired (like in my case), and 2. shading smooth with auto smooth ticked?

Comment: Flat shading is exactly the same as marking all edges as sharp (and both are exactly the same as using autosmooth with a 0 degree angle specified.)  Smooth shading with sharp edges allows some sharp edges and some smooth edges.  Autosmooth gives permission to Blender to try to figure out whether an angle should be sharp or not (on the basis of the autosmooth angle you specify.)

Answer (score 2):

Smooth shading works roughly as follows:

- Faces are triangulated by the renderer. Each triangle is necessarily planar, and so has a definite normal.
- Vertices are given a 'Vertex Normal', which is a (sometimes weighted) average of the normals of the triangles which meet at them.
- The normals of shading-points within the triangles are re-calculated as (barycentric) interpolations of the Vertex Normals at their corners.
- The light-response of each point on the surface uses the interpolated Vertex Normal, rather than the normal of the underlying geometry.

If you switch on 'Smooth Shading', you are telling the renderer to use the interpolated normals. Sometimes the interpolated normals are a weirdly inaccurate version of the shading you might expect from the geometry.

You have the option of *splitting* the normals. Either by asking for 'Flat Shading', which splits all the normals, or by switching on 'AutoSmooth' in the object's Data tab > Normals panel, which splits some of them, usually if faces meet at above a threshold angle:

[image]

If the normals are split, then each face uses its own true normal, not the interpolation.

On the left, the cubes show the kind of anomaly that can be produced by smooth shading. On the right, the vertex normals have been split.

**Sharp**

If you mark an edge 'Sharp', you are telling the smoothing algorithm never to interpolate normals over that edge.  Then the adjacent faces are shaded like the cube on the right, above. You have to switch on 'AutoSmooth' to make split normals available, and see the effect. It produces a very sharp edge, with absolutely flat shading on each side - never found in nature. But good for stylised renders, diagrams, or if you have a *very* low poly-budget.

There is another way of preventing direct interpolation between large faces with very different normals...

**Bevelling**

... putting little intermediate faces between them. Each little face will get its own normal, easing the transition:

[image]

On the left, above: Sharp. On the right, Bevelled. Bevelling will produce a more natural result; it picks up highlights, and retains a subtle gradation across the larger faces. If you want any naturalism in your render, it's preferable. Your (painted?) street-lamp would look very peculiar if its edges had no highlights, and its surfaces were icy-flat.

BTW.. marking an edge 'Sharp' has a secondary function in Blender. It can be a signal to the *Split Edges* modifier to physically split the faces, not just the normals, doubling up the marked edges. If the modifier is applied, the faces can be moved independently.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give such a thorough breakdown Robin! This was very helpful.